# SQL Server - Scripting a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to create a clone table(same table structure) with an already existing table. I know one of the ways is :

```
Right click on table name -> Script table as -> Create To -> New query editor
```

I also found out another way would be:

```
Right click on database name -> Tasks -> Generate scripts -> choose the tables you want
```

Along the way, you can set scripting options to script whatever I want such as constraint,indexes,triggers,etc.

So what would be the difference between these two methods?
As far I tried both method and both produce the same outcome, or at least that's what I see.

I do realize that all the STATISTICS in a table cannot be scripted if I opt for the first method but if I go for the second method, I could script all the statistics to the clone table by setting the statistic settings to script stats and histograms as well. This would not be possible in the first method.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Thanks

Comment: I believe there is no difference I think, except one is to clone a single table. the other is to clone as many tables as you like. One thing that catches me out here, is triggers is omitted by default in the generate Scripts option

Comment: which one you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my Knowledge Both are same. Ie. Create To-> New Query window also generates the script but it only allowers you to create the table - You Can't specify what all need to be included in the create script since this is a default template. It will by default generate the scripts for all the constraints available in the table.

Whereas Using the Generate Scripts option, you will have more control over the script that is being generated, Like you can Generate the script for the inserts, You can choose whether generate the script for keys and constraints or not etc.

So If you just want to generate the Create script, then you can right-click the table and choose to create to --> New Query window or If you wish to have more control over the process then maybe try the Generate scripts option.

Also, If your requirement is just a table with the same structure as well as data - Without the constraints, Then you can try the Select * INTO option

```
SELECT * INTO T2 FROM T1
```

Please visit these link for more info 
[Generate Scripts for Data in the Tables of SQL Server](https://blogs.perficient.com/delivery/blog/2016/10/18/generate-scripts-for-data-present-in-the-tables-of-sql-server/)

[Options for scripting SQL Server database objects](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1503/options-for-scripting-sql-server-database-objects/)

Comment: What about the statistics scripting? I couldn't carry forward stats using the first method.

Comment: might want to put a where 1=2 at the end of that clause, otherwise you will be waiting ages if the table has say 500 million rows in it

Comment: The first method script for an exact copy of the table with all constraints but No Data. So If you want to pull the stats data of the table like the values, maybe you should use the 2nd option of Generate Scripts

Comment: @AbBennett Yes, But That will Create a copy without data.

Comment: Jaya, what if i want to script just the keys,indexes,constraint,triggers and stats but not the data or create table script, would 2nd method be good?

Comment: Yes, You can choose Script Data to No.

Comment: If i want to script for 10 tables, can i separate to 10 sql files?

Comment: Yes, You can choose whether all tables need to be in the same file or Generate separate files for each table. And there are so many customization options available.

Comment: I have added 2 links for additional reference in the answer

Answer (score -1):

With below option you will not be able to generate the script to copy the data

```
Right click on table name -> Script table as -> Create To -> New query editor
```

But if you are generating the script from Task, you will be able to copy structure as well as data

```
Right click on database name -> Tasks -> Generate scripts -> choose the tables you want
```

Comment: What about scripting statistics? The first method wouldn't allow me to script all the stats to the clone table. Even if I set the scripting options to script stats.